# Create custom styled buttons class like the new Android Market has?

Tags: android, user-interface, button

Would it be possible to create a class which you could pass four or so variables into that would create a button that looks similar to the new Android 3.0 Market link buttons?  I am trying to learn all aspects of Android design. The button in question is below:

[image]

I think it would be cool if you could in your code create a new button that looks similar to this by going.

`myButton = new myButton(hex value, mainText, subText, image resource);`

The hex would determine the color bar, the mainText the Title(Apps), etc.

Is this possible? Thanks...any similar examples would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, Create a composite view which exposes all these functionalities.

- Extend a View class (CustomButton).
- Create a layout with all these sub-widgets ( 2 textviews + 1 image)
- Inlfate the layout and add it to your CustomButton
- Expose methods in your Custombutton class which interact with the sub-widgets (2 TVs + 1 IV)